# My Developer Org Hits Governor Limits when sending emails

Tags: force.com, administration, isv

From some reason I get a  Governor Limit error in my development org while trying to test email sending functionality.

Here is the governor limit error:

> System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0;
>   first error: SINGLE_EMAIL_LIMIT_EXCEEDED, Failed to send email: []

I probably sent up to 50 emails today, which is very low, I assumed that the limit will stand on 1000. Did you happen to encounter this? do you know if there are ways to bypass this besides waiting for tomorrow?

By the way, I have been using this development org for four years now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you site refers to individual emails, not mass emails; from *CHAPTER 2: Force.com Platform Limits* of the [Limits Cheatsheet](http://na9.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf):

> In Developer Edition organizations and organizations evaluating Salesforce during a trial period... your organization can send single emails to a maximum of 15 email addresses per day.

Also, note this is 15 *addresses*, not emails.  If you can reuse email address you have already used, you should be able to continue testing.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently DE org has lower limits than other org.
In Developer Edition organizations and organizations evaluating Salesforce during a trial period, your organization can send mass email to no more than 10 external email addresses per day.